# Qt setGeometry: Unable to set geometry

Tags: c++, qt

Why?

```
setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 22x22+320+145 on QWidgetWindow/'WidgetClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  116x22+320+145 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 22x22, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
```

The project is:

project.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled5
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Adding setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300); in Widget constructor removes the issue. But the window will not be positioned beautifully at the center of the screen.

Comment: do you want your application window at the center of screen ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This warning happens (at least to me) when the size of the widget results to be very small.

Set a minimum size for your widget (so it will be automatically positioned), like:

```
 // Widget constructor

 QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
 setLayout(vLayout);

 setMinimumSize(200,200);
```

You should also parent your widget to a `QMainWindow`, but will still work.

Comment: thanks a lot.. I was missing to set the parent for a ComboBox widget and your solution helped..

Comment: It worked very well directly on the main.cpp where I instantiated MainWindow: **mainWindow.setMinimumSize(200, 200);**.

Comment: Worked for my dialog box ! strange I never had this problem with Linux, I encountered it with Windows.

Comment: It kind of worked for my dialog box. I just set minimum sizes for width and height on QT Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `adjustSize()`

Looks to be the problem:
[Why am I getting QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry warning with Qt 5.12.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307407/why-am-i-getting-qwindowswindowsetgeometry-unable-to-set-geometry-warning-wit)

A possible solution:
[Qt Unable to set geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700394/qt-unable-to-set-geometry)