# Qt Unable to set geometry

Tags: qt, resize

I am receiving a warning in Qt about setting geometry every time I try to open a new window or Dialog. It even happens with `QDialogInput`. And I'm not trying to set the geometry, just calling the window already gives me a warning. Here's an example:

main.cpp

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();


for(int i=0;i<graphPoints;i++)
    series->append(i,(qrand()%5)+20);

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setTitle("X vs Y teste");

QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QDialog *graph = new QDialog(this);
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(graph);
layout->addWidget(chartView);
graph->setLayout(layout);
graph->exec();
```

warning:

```
setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 116x30+619+380 on QWidgetWindow/'QDialogClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  116x91+619+380 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 91x91, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
```

This was not a problem until recently I tried to use `setGeometry(200,200,200,200)` and nothing happened.

Any idea what this may be?

### EDIT

I made a very simple program. Ony included `QInputDialog` and called `QInputDialog::getString()`. Here's the example:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QInputDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QInputDialog::getText(this,"title","label");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

output:

```
Starting C:\Users\socc\Documents\Qt\build-VerySimple-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\VerySimple.exe...
setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 116x30+100+105 on QWidgetWindow/'QInputDialogClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  178x90+100+105 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 178x90, maximum size: 524287x90).
C:/Users/socc/Documents/Qt/build-VerySimple-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/VerySimple.exe exited with code 0
```

Comment: If you have a layout, eg:QHBoxLayout. The widget in the layout cannot use `setGeometry` directly.

Comment: So how do I set the geometry using the layout?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, this warning can show for cases like: if using ui form editor and you manually drag a widget such that resulting geometry can't fit in screen at run time, Or more generally, when a *widget* geometry is smaller than the layout contents, it isn't a serious issue because the widget will automatically adjust and render correctly, but this issue can be solved by insuring the widget gets enough space before rendered, this is done by adjusting its size to contents, thus try:

```
graph->adjustSize();
graph->exec();
```

On the other hand, while the issue is not reproducible to me, with `graph->setGeometry(200,200,200,200);` but it only appeared at ((200,200,100,100), it could be your geometry width/height is smaller than your chart view dimensions, try to adjust them to higher geometry width/height to accommodate your chart.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. And using `graph->adjustSize()` indeed worked. But still can't set the geometry. And this happen using a static method of QDialogInput too? like `QDialogInput::getItem()`?

Comment: If its only this code in question, then yes I could set geometry for the dialog just before `exec()` ... try to find for another reason that could cause the issue which is not seen in this code

Comment: I will make an edit with a very simple example of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the other case in Update where the static was used to create a **window** with little information see [static public members](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html) .. you are not setting a **window** type or any other hint for the dialog.

**A widget that is not embedded in a parent widget is called a window.** ... *it is also possible to create windows without such decoration using suitable* [window flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html))

you need to use the static with either an explicit window type (ex: `Qt::Popup`):

```
QInputDialog::getText(this,"title","label",QLineEdit::Normal,"",nullptr,Qt::Popup);
```

Or a window hint (ex. `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint`)

```
QInputDialog::getText(this,"title","label",QLineEdit::Normal,"",nullptr,Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

Comment: I'm late to the party but other statics like QColorDialog::getColor() do not have such flags and will raise the setGeometry warning message